# Xampp won't connect with Sqlite: could not find driver

Tags: php, sqlite, xampp

Some months ago, I started using sqlite through xampp. Worked perfectly fine. Then, I had to uninstall Xampp. After that, I just couldn't connect a database with Sqlite. It just keeps saying `could not find driver`.

In terminal, I did `php -m`. I could see pdo_sqlite in php modules. But also the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Can't load module 'D:\Program Files\XAMPP\php\ext\sqlite3' as it's linked with 2.25, but the core is linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Can't load module 'D:\Program Files\XAMPP\php\ext\sqlite3' as it's linked with 2.25, but the core is linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
```

Then, I stored Sqlite3.exe in `D:\Program Files\XAMPP\php\ext\sqlite3` but the error is still the same.

In `php.ini`, I uncommented the following:

```
extension=sqlite3
extension=pdo_sqlite
sqlite3.extension_dir = D:\Program Files\XAMPP\php\ext
```

**Edit:**

I added sqlite3.dll in the `ext` directory, and `extension=php_sqlite3.dll` in my `php.ini`. Now sqlite3 is showing in `php -m`, but when connecting still returning Could not find driver. And the same errors in the terminal

Comment: If you mean that your PHP bundle doesn't include the SQLite extension and you got the DLLs from somewhere else, that could certainly explain the issue. Extension binaries must match with your exact PHP environment: version, architecture, VC, thread-safety... Official Windows binaries do include SQLite but, unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Xampp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I didn't get to knew where the problem exactly was.

When I visited https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.requirements.php I saw that you need `libsqlite3.dll`. I went on more research. I had to copy `libsqlite3.dll` from the `/php` folder to the `/apache/bin` folder. That didn't solve the issues in the terminal, but it did connect to the Sqlite database.